# Building website with MSBuild form cmd prompt giving error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Im trying to build a website from the cmd prompt with the help of MSBuild and its giving error

`e:\Projects\XXXXXXX\Default.aspx(149): error CS0433: The type
 'CommonControls_RelatedControls_LatestContents' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\Mic
rosoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\XXXXXXX\7247a6d3\6c34
e579\App_Web_2nkvgs2h.dll' and 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\T
emporary ASP.NET Files\XXXXXXX\7247a6d3\6c34e579\App_Web_x01eius3.dll' [C:\Do
cuments and Settings\<username>\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\XXXXXXX\
XXXXXXX.metaproj]`

i use the command

`MSBuild XXXXXX.sln`

but when i compile the same form the Visual Studio is get build fine.

I also tried aftr deleting the files in the .net temporary files folder but same issue again, not able to compile it even once from `cmd prompt`

Note:-Its a website not a web-project so i only have sln not project file